# min and max of NumPy arrays in Python within a certain range

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max, min

I am reading data from the sensor and its data always change over time, its data are between 0 and 255 as `np.array`.

I'd like to find min and max values between 3 and 250.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,1, 2, 10, 20, 100, 251, 255])
d = a.min()
c = a.max()
print (d,c)
```

The output is: `(0, 255)`

I'd like to be `(10, 100)`

Sometimes `a = np.array([0,1, 3, 10, 20, 100, 249, 255])`

I'd like to be `(3, 249)`

Please, your help.

Comment: Why are the max 100 and 249? as opposed to 255?

Comment: @SayandipDutta, I'd like to find min and max values between 3 and 250.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is:

```
>>> a
array([0,1, 2, 10, 20, 100, 251, 255])
>>> arr_min = a[(a >= 3) & (a <= 250)].min()
>>> arr_max = a[(a >= 3) & (a <= 250)].max()
>>> (arr_min, arr_max)
(10, 100)
```

Other one is with `scipy.stats.describe`:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import describe
>>> describe(a[(3 <= a) & (a <= 250)]).minmax
(10, 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add conditions then check `min` and `max`

```py
a = np.array([0,1, 2, 10, 20, 100, 251, 255])
print(a[(a>=3) & (a<=250)].min())
print(a[(a>=3) & (a<=250)].max())
```

```
10
100
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The output is: (0, 255).

Comment: I am sorry, did not understand your question @Redhwan

Comment: Actually In the first time I though the start limit and end limit were excluded. Then after you modified your question I changed my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own functions with using the existing in `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

def my_min(input, min_, max_):
    m = input.min()

    if m > max_:
        return max_
    elif m < min_:
        return min_
    else:
        return m

def my_max(input, min_, max_):
    m = input.max()

    if m > max_:
        return max_
    elif m < min_:
        return min_
    else:
        return m

l1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 10, 20, 100, 251, 255])
l2 = np.array([0,1, 3, 10, 20, 100, 249, 255])

print("({}, {})".format(my_min(l1, 10, 100), my_max(l1, 10, 100)))
print("({}, {})".format(my_min(l2, 3, 250), my_max(l2, 3, 250)))
```

Output:

```
(10, 100)
(3, 250)
```

---

> Call the function like `my_min(array, min, max)`

Comment: This isn't too efficient considering the data is read from a sensor.

Comment: Of course, I did that with the right answer, Your code needs to edit for giving the output (10, 100).  What about  a = np.array([0,1, 3, 10, 20, 100, 249, 255])

Comment: Well okay I edited the answer. But it is giving the right output, it is up to you to use it as you want.

Comment: print("({}, {})".format(my_min(l1, 3, 250), my_max(l1, 3, 250)))
print("({}, {})".format(my_min(l2, 3, 250), my_max(l2, 3, 250)))
(3, 250)
(3, 250), sorry, it is still wrong.

Comment: If min value is 9,  I need to change the code every time?

Comment: No you just call the function and change the parameters. I don't understand what is the problem here ... :/